# R logistic glmnet penalty.factor

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glmnet, lasso-regression

I am trying to run logistic regression by using LASSO in glmnet package. And I need to force the model to include certain parameters. However, I got an error.

```
> cv.lasso = cv.glmnet(x,y,family="binomial",alpha = 1,penalty.factor = penalty)
Error: Matrices must have same number of columns in rbind2(.Call(dense_to_Csparse, x), y)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: from glmnet Fortran code (error code -1); Convergence for 1th lambda value not reached after maxit=100000 iterations; solutions for larger lambdas returned 
2: In getcoef(fit, nvars, nx, vnames) :
an empty model has been returned; probably a convergence issue
```

x has 95 variables that are all binary (0 or 1). I have to force 3 variables to be included so I set their penalty.factor = 0.

```
   > penalty
   [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   [38] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   [75] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

if I remove `penalty.factor`, it will work but I have to force those three variables to be included. However, when I keep `penalty.factor` and remove `family = "binomial"`, it was running but it is not a binary logistic regression anymore. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Edit: Since I don't have a solution and I am facing pressure to show results ASAP, I choose to use the variables selected by LASSO combined with those three mandatory variables to run a regular logit regression. Somehow I think there will be an issue by doing this...

Thank you!

Comment: This is a convergence issue. Since all of your features are binary and this is a logistic model, this is plausibly due to the Hauck-Dauber effect.

Comment: @user777 Thanks for your answer. Sorry I am not familiar with convergence issue. do you have any suggestions to fix it?

Comment: Check out the Hauck Dauber effect tag on CV.SE.

Comment: @user777 I don't think it is related to Hauck Dauber effect, since none of those three variables (the ones I want to keep) can perfectly separate the outcome.

Comment: What about in combination?

Comment: @user777 do you also suggest me to combine them? I feel like it will be problematic. So far I see many insignificant predictors (by using regular glm, I can see z values and p values)

Comment: @user777 sorry I guess I misunderstood. You meant combining those three variables?

Comment: My question is "Is there a combination of those three that results in perfect separation?"

Comment: @user777 Thanks. No, I don't think so (to prove it, I tried to use only three of them to run a logit regression). On the other hand, if they can separate perfectly, I don't even need LASSO.

Comment: In that case, try playing with the sequence of lambda values.

Comment: @Sycorax: it's called **[Hauck-Donner effect](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/hauck-donner-effect/info)**

Comment: @smci Thanks for the correction. I was typing on my phone and it got mangled by auto-correct.